# Make frequency table of unique rows in pandas dataframe containing missing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I want to create a frequency table for pandas dataframes which contain missing values. Here is a sample dataframe with missing values to illustrate my problem:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
car_names = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['Batmobile','Toyota Corolla','Bike',
                                     'Bike','Batmobile'],
      'hp': [1000,120,np.nan,np.nan,900]})
car_attr = pd.DataFrame({"name": ["Bike","Toyota Corolla"],
                         "color": ["blue","red"]})
cars = car_names.merge(car_attr,how='left',on='name')
```

```
    name            hp      color
0   Batmobile       1000.0  NaN
1   Toyota Corolla  120.0   red
2   Bike            NaN     blue
3   Bike            NaN     blue
4   Batmobile       900.0   NaN
```

**My desired output**, a frequency table which shows one combination of values occurred twice:

```
    name            hp      color    count
0   Bike            NaN     blue     2
1   Batmobile       1000.0  NaN      1
2   Toyota Corolla  120.0   red      1
3   Batmobile       900.0   NaN      1
```

I have tried using groupby().size() but this method excludes rows with missing values (ie. every row in my dataframe except for the second row):

```py
cars.groupby(['name','hp','color']).size()
```

```
name            hp     color
Toyota Corolla  120.0  red      1
```

Another method I have tried is converting the pandas dataframe to a list of lists (where each row is a list) and using the list.index() function to count occurrences of unique rows, but I run into this strange error:

```py
my_rows = cars.values.tolist()
my_rows_dedup = cars.drop_duplicates().values.tolist()

for x in my_rows:
    print(x)
    print('Row index: ', my_rows.index(x),
    ' Unique Index: ', my_rows_dedup.index(x))
```

```py
['Batmobile', 1000.0, nan]
Row index:  0  Unique Index:  0
['Toyota Corolla', 120.0, 'red']
Row index:  1  Unique Index:  1
['Bike', nan, 'blue']

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-100-f17351883e95> in <module>
      4 for x in my_rows:
      5     print(x)
----> 6     print('Row index: ', my_rows.index(x), ' Unique Index: ', my_rows_dedup.index(x))

ValueError: ['Bike', nan, 'blue'] is not in list
```

This error doesn't make sense to me since ['Bike', nan, 'blue'] is a value in my_rows_dedup.

Comment: The dataframe you show in your question is different from the one you construct with pd.dataframe

Comment: My mistake, I changed the dataframe slightly to make it shorter and neglected to update the code on here. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you want to handle null values, you can just fill these first and then replace later if you want to convert them back to a `NaN` value

```
x = 'g8h.|$hTdo+jC9^@'    
(cars.fillna(x).groupby(['name','hp','color']).size().reset_index()
               .rename(columns={0 : 'count'}).replace(x,np.NaN))
            name         hp     color   count
    0   Batmobile       900.0   NaN     1
    1   Batmobile       1000.0  NaN     1
    2   Bike            NaN     blue    2
    3   Toyota Corolla  120.0   red     1
```

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't work if whatever value you fill the missings with is in the data. I'm looking for a general solution that could be used on any dataset.

Comment: you could fill it with a random string like `'ZaX£mz$%1'` and then replace it with NaN, check my updated solution.

Comment: Yes, seems to be a workable solution although I added a step to randomly generate the string and make sure it isn't already a value in the data.

Comment: @cambonator awesome, can you edit my post to add that in (curious to see it!)? Also don't forget to tick the solution which helped you

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit overkill for some, but this is a function which is along the lines of DataNovice's answer. I generate a random string to fill the NA values and make sure that the random string is not in my dataset. I also create a percent column and do some formatting for display in a jupyter notebook (hiding the index, formatting commas and percents).

```py
import random
import string
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display

# column names (optional) defined as string or list of strings
# Returns frequency table that includes missing values for df
# n limits the output to the first n rows
def tidy_count(df,columns=None,count_col='n',return_df=False,n=None):
    # subset df by columns if specified
    if columns != None:
        if type(columns) != list:
            columns = [columns]
        df = df[columns]

    col_vals = df.columns.values # all column values

    # Find all distinct values in the dataset for both data values
    # and column names, store in the list allvals
    pds_allvals = pd.Series(col_vals) 
    for col in col_vals:
        pds_allvals = pd.concat([pds_allvals,df[str(col)]]).drop_duplicates()
    allvals = pds_allvals.tolist()
    #print(allvals)

    filler_val=None
    # generate a random string for filler_val until it is 
    # not something that occurs in our data
    loop_iters=1
    while filler_val == None or filler_val in allvals:
        filler_val = ''.join(random.choices(string.digits + string.ascii_letters, k=np.random.randint(4,12)))  
        loop_iters += 1
        if loop_iters > 8:
            print('Error: Cannot find unique string to fill NA values.')
            break
    #print(filler_val)

    # reset count column name until it is unique among column names
    loop_iters=1
    while count_col in col_vals:
        if count_col == 'n':
            count_col = count_col + 'n'
        else:
            count_col = count_col + '_'

        if loop_iters > 8:
            print('Error: Cannot find unique string for counter column.')
            break    
        loop_iters += 1

    freq_table = df.fillna(filler_val).groupby([str(x) for x in col_vals]).size().\
            reset_index(name=count_col).\
         replace(filler_val,np.NaN).sort_values(count_col,ascending=False)

    freq_table['percent'] = freq_table[count_col] / sum(freq_table[count_col])

    # limit frequency table to first n rows if specified
    if n != None:
        freq_table = freq_table.head(n)

    # Formatted pandas display for jupyter notebooks
    df_display = display(freq_table.style.hide_index().\
                format({'n': '{:,}','percent': '{0:.1%}'}))

    if return_df == False:
        df_display
    else:
        df_display
        return(freq_table)
```

Sample use on a dataset from the seaborn package:

```py
## Import a dataset from seaborn and add missing values at random
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
planets = sns.load_dataset("planets")
import numpy as np
planets_method = planets.sample(frac=.40,random_state=42)
planets_year = planets.sample(frac=.20,random_state=84)
planets_method['method'] = np.nan
planets_year['year'] = np.nan

planets_combi = pd.concat([planets.\
                    drop(planets_method.index.union(planets_year.index)),
                          planets_method,planets_year]).sort_index()

## Use the function above to create a frequency table
# Note that it is cut off at row 7 (n=7) for display purposes
tidy_count(planets_combi,['method','year'],n=7)
```

```
method               year   n   percent
Radial Velocity      nan    104 9.2%
Transit              nan    82  7.3%
nan                  2011   70  6.2%
Transit              2012   56  5.0%
Radial Velocity      2011   52  4.6%
nan                  2013   48  4.3%
nan                  2010   47  4.2%
```

Answer (score 0):

You could work around the NaN problem by replacing them while you groupby, and restore them after. Something like this maybe:

```
# Fillna, groupby columns and count duplicates
counts = cars.fillna(-1).groupby(cars.columns.tolist()).agg(len)
# Reshape the dataframe
cars_no_dups = pd.DataFrame(counts.reset_index().to_records()).set_index("index")
# Restore duplicates
cars_no_dups[cars_no_dups==-1] = np.nan
```